# Can't save console output as Ruby variable

Tags: ruby, bash, variables, input, console

I am having trouble saving the output of a command in console into Ruby as a variable. I am trying to save information of a .p12 file in as a variable `p12_info`. This is what I have tried so far.

```
file = File.read("certificate.p12")
p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(file, "")
p12_info = `openssl pkcs12 -in #{p} -info -noout -passin pass:""`
print "Info: "
puts p12_info
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
File name: certificate.p12
MAC Iteration 1
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
Info:
```

The console command seems to be running when I try to set the variable p_12, but doesn't actually get saved into p12_info.

Alternatively if I try this:

```
p12_info = `echo "foo`
print "Info: "
puts p12_info
```

Then I get this output, which is what Im going for:

```
File name: certificate.p12
Info: foo
```

Any ideas about why this could be happening will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

@tadman - Thanks so much for the help. You are correct, the command did in fact output with the appended `> /dev/null`. Unfortunately, I am having trouble figuring out how to use popen3. I am very unfamiliar with all this..I've tried:

```
Open3.popen3(`openssl pkcs12 -in bad_certificate.p12 -info -noout -passin pass:""`) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  pid = wait_thr.pid # pid of the started process.
  p12_info = wait_thr.stderr # Process::Status object returned.
}
```

To no avail. Any pointers that could lead me in the right direction? Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the output is going to STDOUT? You can test on the shell with `openssl ... > /dev/null` and if you still see output then it's writing to STDERR instead. Then you'll have to use [`popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

Comment: I've responded in an edit above. Thanks!

Comment: Is that what you put for the `popen3` call? It should be in regular quotes, not back-ticks.

Comment: @mbratch yeah, that was a mistake. tadman pointed me in the right direction, but nevertheless, many thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few things. One is that `popen3` takes a string argument, and backticks cause an external shell call that coincidentally returns a string.

The backtick convention comes from the `bash` shell where it's used to inline the result of a command:

```
ls -l `which ls`
```

This could expand to:

```
ls -l '/bin/ls'
```

With that in mind, what you should have is this:

```
Open3.popen3('openssl pkcs12 -in bad_certificate.p12 -info -noout -passin pass:""') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  # stderr is a standard IO filehandle
  p12_info = stderr.read
end
```